# Schedule the Publishing date of a file in Document Library using CSOM

Tags: workflow, document-library, publishing, schedule

I am having a hard time to schedule the publishing date of a document uploaded to a sharepoint document library. Basicaly, what I want is to upload a file to a document library and to schedule it´s publishing for a future date, using CSOM. Then someone should approve this (file content and scheduled date and time for publishing).

I am able to upload the document to the document library and to start the approval workflow automatically (when the document is uploaded), but I don´t know how to set the publishing date using client side object model.

Apparently all I need to do is to set up the properties ScheduledItem.StartDate and ScheduledItem.EndDate, but I just can´t manage to do it.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add "Scheduled Start Date" site column to your library. By default document libraries don't have this column.

And update its value programmatically. Refer to  [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-schedule-an-item-in-sharepoint-2010/) for details.

Let us know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Amit, first of all thanks for your help! I already added the column "Schedule Start Date". The solution on the post you suggested needs to run in a sharepoint server, I would like to do it using Client side object model, since it will be a webservice runing in a machine without sharepoint server instaled. Do you have any idea how can I do it using only microsoft.sharepoint.client libraries?

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to get or set the startdate using only CSOM?  The examples in msdn use microsoft.sharepoint.publishing instead of microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing... the method getscheduleditem is not available in CSOM, trying to instantiate a scheduleitem I couldnt find/cretae the requested parameter "Obeject path"... in other words, I couldn´t find a way to instantiate the Scheduleditem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lele I haven't done this using CSOM. Let me see when can i get a chance to try this out. Would love to share with you, if I find something useful.